# Disable option "open output file after running algorithm"

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

Whenever I run a model in QGIS there is a dialog box asking for the set parameters. There the option "open output file after running algorithm" is always checked.

is there a setting to have this box always unchecked?

I have checked if there is something in the Options-Processing menu but found nothing. My best bet is that I have to change some value in the Advanced option, but I don't know how the dialog box is named in the QGIS environment. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: did you find out how to achieve this ? I am looking also for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export your model as a Python script.
[image: export model button]

In the code you will find that each output parameter has `createByDefault=True` in its instantiator, for example:

```
self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('verwalt', 'Verwaltungsgrenzen', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))
self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('infra', 'Infrastrukturen', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))
self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('bauten', 'Bauten', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))
```

Just change `createByDefault=True` to `createByDefault=False` for the outputs you don't wan to automatically load